# Synonym to match

Tags: word-choice

How do I rephrase "It's a match!"  as in dating?

I want to make the phrase a little less generic and more catchy.

Comment: It would help if you explain more clearly what you are trying to convey.  I've never heard "It's a match!" applied to dating.  "They are a good match" is used to say that two people are compatible, likely to get along.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a message on a dating app which pops up when the computer thinks it's found a potential partner? If so it sounds very mechanistic and unromantic to me. Then again, perhaps I'm just an old romantic.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about *made for each other*?

> "After one date, we knew we were *made for each other*. We were a
>   perfect match."